# Is this condition enough for irreducibility?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $f$ is a polynomial in $Z[X]$, such that $f = (X-\alpha_1) ... (X-\alpha_n)$ with $n$ distinct complex, irrational roots. Suppose that $Q[\alpha_i]$ = $Q[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]$ for all $i$.
Question: Does this imply that $f$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: $f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-8)$.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra: +1 for a Clear answer. Expanding your idea we can start with any irreducible quadratic $g(x)$ and  define $f(x)= g(x) g(x+k)$, $k$ an integer. (so this is an additive analogue of your example). Perhaps one can  start with  a cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ and define $f(x)=\Phi_n(x)\Phi_n(x+k)$; also we can  extend by varying the number of 'translated polynomials'.

Comment: @Anonymous, the edit doesn't change the counterexample

Comment: Correct - sorry. Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a counterexample in which $Z[\alpha_i] = Z[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]$  for all $i$?

Comment: @Anonymous, it occurs to me my counterexample wouldn't have worked if you had specifiied the number of irrational roots $n$ to be *prime*.  (The edit requiring the roots to be irrational was a good one -- I was in the process of editing my answer to take note of the even simpler, and completely general, counterexample $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)$, when you pulled the rug out from under it!)  You might try working this out for yourself, and if you get stuck post it as a new question (preferably with a link to this one).

Comment: @Anonymous,  P Vanchinathan's comment should help answer your $Z$-question.

Comment: @Barry Cipra: Indeed, that comment gives easy counterexamples, silly that I didn't notice that! Thanks for all answers!